# Namespace collision with composer dependecies for Shopware 6 Plugin

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I'm writing unit tests for my Shopware Plugin. I've setup the same PHPUnit environment as SwagPayPal.

What I did:

- composer.json

```
[...]
"require": {
  "ext-json": "*",
  "php": ">= 8.0",
  "goetas-webservices/xsd2php-runtime": "^0.2.16",
  "enqueue/stomp": "^0.10.16",
  "shopware/core": "6.4.12.0"
},
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Namespace\\Plugin\\": "src/"
  }
},
"autoload-dev": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Namespace\\Plugin\\Test\\": "tests/"
  }
},
[...]
```

- phpunit.xml.dist `bootstrap="tests/TestBootstrap.php"`
- TestBootstrap.php is a 1:1 copy of the same file from SwagPayPal
  except `->addActivePlugins('SwagCmsExtensions')` was removed. https://github.com/shopwareLabs/SwagPayPal/blob/10694e851a11ac60e98cdb2130e66724611ef9a6/tests/TestBootstrap.php

My tests were all working fine. I now added the following code in one test:

```
$customerRepository = $this->getContainer()->get('customer.repository');
$customerRepository->upsert([$customerData], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

After calling `upsert` it crashes with `Compile Error: Cannot declare class Shopware\Core\Checkout\Promotion\Cart\PromotionProcessor, because the name is already in use`

I can get it working when I run `sudo rm -rf var/cache/test_*` but only once. When running it a second time it crashes again.

It seems it loads Shopware from the vendor folder of the plugin and then also from the root folder. I don't get why it's working the first time, but not a second time.

Edit: I checked all my namespace declarations in the PHP test files and I'm pretty sure they're correct. So I think it's another cause I can't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated my `tests/TestBootstrap.php` to fix my problem.

1. I removed the `->setClassLoader(require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php')` call, so it doesn't load the composer generated stuff anymore.
2. I added the following code so it adds the PSR-4 namespace prefixes for my plugin:

   ```php
   $pluginComposerDir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..');
   $pluginComposerJson = json_decode(file_get_contents($pluginComposerDir . '/composer.json'));

   foreach (['autoload', 'autoload-dev'] as $loader) {
       if (is_object($pluginComposerJson->$loader) && is_object($pluginComposerJson->$loader->{'psr-4'})) {
           foreach ($pluginComposerJson->$loader->{'psr-4'} as $namespace => $path) {
               $classLoader->addPsr4($namespace, $pluginComposerDir . '/' . $path);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

So now I have best of both worlds:

- My plugin only adds the `autoload-dev` namespace(s) for tests.
- It doesn't load the composer dependecies of my plugin, so I get no collisions with the Shopware root or other dependencies
- I need to install my plugin dependencies in the Shopware root and if I don't do it Shopware won't install my extension and warn me about the failed dependencies:

  ```
  Failed Dependency: Required plugin/package "goetas-webservices/xsd2php-runtime ^0.2.16" is missing or not installed and activated
  Failed Dependency: Required plugin/package "enqueue/stomp ^0.10.16" is missing or not installed and activated
  ```

Full `tests/TestBootstrap.php`:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
// based on tests/TestBootstrap.php of SwagPayPal

/*
 * (c) shopware AG <info@shopware.com>
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

use Shopware\Core\TestBootstrapper;

if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/shopware/platform/src/Core/TestBootstrapper.php')) {
    // from Shopware root vendor dir
    require __DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/shopware/platform/src/Core/TestBootstrapper.php';
} elseif (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/shopware/core/TestBootstrapper.php')) {
    // from Shopware root vendor dir
    require __DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/shopware/core/TestBootstrapper.php';
} else {
    throw new Exception('TestBootstrapper not found. Please install Shopware root dependencies.');
}

$classLoader = (new TestBootstrapper())
    ->setProjectDir($_SERVER['PROJECT_ROOT'] ?? dirname(__DIR__, 4))
    ->setLoadEnvFile(true)
    ->setForceInstallPlugins(true)
    ->addCallingPlugin()
    ->bootstrap()
    ->getClassLoader();

$pluginComposerDir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..');
$pluginComposerJson = json_decode(file_get_contents($pluginComposerDir . '/composer.json'));

foreach (['autoload', 'autoload-dev'] as $loader) {
    if (is_object($pluginComposerJson->$loader) && is_object($pluginComposerJson->$loader->{'psr-4'})) {
        foreach ($pluginComposerJson->$loader->{'psr-4'} as $namespace => $path) {
            $classLoader->addPsr4($namespace, $pluginComposerDir . '/' . $path);
        }
    }
}

return $classLoader;
```

Edit: adjusted `tests/TestBootstrap.php` to load `TestBootrapper` class from Shopware root.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the classes being autoloaded multiple times. It's hard to say what causes this without knowing all the code involved. Rather than copying from an existing plugin I'd suggest you start from scratch and [follow the documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/testing/php-unit) on how to setup a clean environment for your tests.

Comment: We did the setup from scratch but then we required additional dependencies and wanted to have the `Namespace\Plugin\Test` namespace. We then had a look at SwagPayPal which is an official Shopware AG plugin and for our previous tests that setup worked perfectly. Only now after adding the call to `$customerRepository->upsert` it fails.
Are there other ways to have additional dependencies and the test namespace?